# Is SharedPreferences Enough for me?

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I want to save 15 arraylist from user,and 10-15 int value.Can I use sharedpreferences or should I use sqlLite ? I dont wanna use SqlLite actually can u help me ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use whatever you want.  The question is how easy it is to access you data in the way you want to do it.  SharedPreferences makes it easy to read and write values.  SQL makes it a bit harder to just read and write values, but makes searching, expressing relationships, and constraining data far easier.  Use what makes sense for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
String myString = new JSONObject().put("JSON", "Hello, World!").toString();
print(myString);
```

It produces the string `{"JSON": "Hello, World"}`.
Just save value by creating JSON Object and parse it when you needed. You have to create a JSON object and save an array list in JSON array then save it shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set `ArrayList` to `SharedPreferences`. `SharedPreferences` is for small data.

You have to create a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` like this :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("YOUR QUERY TO CREATE YOUR TABLE");
}
```

and here is an example of how to insert values on your table :

```
public void insertListData(List<Data> dataList) {
    super.open();

    ContentValues values;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
        values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("COLUMN", dataList.get(i).getData());
        ... //all values that you have

        getBdd().insert("YOUR_TABLE, null, values);
    }
    super.close();
}
```

Good Luck!